# How to write a comment and reply with django with this model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-comments

I'm a newcomer and I have this problem that I can't send this comment to database it just refreshes the page and nothing happens.

```
def blog_detail(request , id):

    post = Post.objects.get(pk = id , status = True)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    # Comment posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_content = request.POST['comment_content']

        if comment_content == '' or comment_content == None :
            messages.error(request , 'comment is empty')


        try:
            comment = Comment.objects.get(body=comment_content,name=MyUser.first_name,email=MyUser.email,active=False)
        except:
            Comment.DoesNotExist()
            new_comment = None      
    
    return render(request, 'blog/blog-detail.html', {'post': post,
                                           'comments': comments,
                                                                                   })
```

this is my model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)
```

I can't idenity the problem

Comment: You `.get(...)`, instead of saving a comment but since you wrap it in a `try`, you of course can not see that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new_comment` variable is not being used after it's set to `None`, so remove it. Additionally, the code does not show any logic for saving the comment to the database, try to use the following view:

```py
def blog_detail(request , id):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=id, status=True)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)

    # Comment posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_content = request.POST.get('comment_content')

        if not comment_content:
            messages.error(request, 'Comment is empty')
        else:
            try:
                comment = Comment.objects.get(
                    body=comment_content,
                    name=request.user.first_name,
                    email=request.user.email,
                    active=False,
                    post=post
                )
                messages.error(request, 'You have already submitted this comment.')
            except Comment.DoesNotExist:
                comment = Comment.objects.create(
                    post=post,
                    name=request.user.first_name,
                    email=request.user.email,
                    body=comment_content,
                    active=True
                )
                messages.success(request, 'Comment submitted successfully.')
                return redirect('blog_detail', id=id)

    return render(request, 'blog/blog-detail.html', {'post': post, 'comments': comments})
```

The exact view would not work, since it assumes the following things:

1. This assumes that the user is logged in and the `request.user` object contains the necessary details. If the user is not logged in, you may need to modify the code to prompt them to log in or provide their name and email address before submitting the comment.
2. Here `redirect("blog_detail"...)` is added as you should always return an `HttpResponseRedirect` after dealing with `POST` data, the tip is not specific to Django, it's a good web practice in general. So you may have different `namw` of view, so you can change it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The line `comment = Comment.objects.get(body=comment_content,name=MyUser.first_name,email=MyUser.email,active=False)` does not actually create a new comment.

In order to create a comment you need to use the class constructor for your class then use the .save() function. [See documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#:%7E:text=Creating%20objects&text=To%20create%20an%20object%2C%20instantiate,save%20it%20to%20the%20database.&text=This%20performs%20an%20INSERT%20SQL,method%20has%20no%20return%20value.)

So in order to create and save a comment you would use the following code

```py
new_comment = Comment(post=post,body=comment_content,name=MyUser.first_name,email=MyUser.email,active=False)
new_comment.save()
```